# application/x-httpd-php opening rather than pages?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, .htaccess

For some reason, no matter what page I try to open (.php, .html, .html, etc) my server trys to save it, rather than displaying the page. However, I do get the "It Works!" page for the main domain, it's only when I try to display a page on a sub-directory that it fails.

I researched the problem, and I placed a .htaccess file in the directory of the pages that I'm attempting open with the code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html .htm
AddHandler applicaton/x-httpd-php5 .php .htm .html .my
```

I'm running the latest version of apache and php5 which is installed as the "php5" module.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could post your httpd configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```

Comment: That didn't seem to help. Just to be sure, the .htaccess file goes in the same subfolder as index.html? I was never really sure whether I got the .htaccess system setup properly.

Comment: Yeah it goes in the root of your site, but try what i suggested in the apache config, oh and is this CentOS or Debian or ...?

Comment: It's Ubuntu, and I'll try it in the config.

Comment: try this : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Troubleshooting%20PHP%205

Comment: Still not working. I think it's a problem with my apache configurationas I'm getting  "VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results" errors on restart.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused for me because `mod_php` isn't multithreaded, so I suddenly had lots of PHP problems when I turned on the multithreaded `mod_spdy`.

I fixed it by following [Google's recommended fix](https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/php): disable `mod_php` and use `mod_fcgid` instead.